# ASP.Net Email and Account validation

Tags: asp.net

i was wondering if any one can advise me on how i can go about implementing a email and account validation feature in my ASP.net website. so when a user creates an account, an email is sent to the email address used, and the user needs to verify that email address to be able to logon.

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suggested workflow..

1. Create an account for the user in your database and mark the account as "to be validated"
2. Produce a random key, maybe a GUID and add it to the users account
3. Email the random key to the user along with a unique URL, e.g www.myurl.com/validateuser.aspx?userid=45532
   To email using asp.net use the system.net.mail namespace - lots of bits on the internet about this.
4. On validateuser.aspx ask user to enter key sent to them in email.
5. Check if keys match. If so update db record to "validated"

**Edit**

By the way, there is a nice answer here on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566776) if you are using forms auth

Comment: Or even add that random key to the mailed url. Then you can immediately process it (when clicked) and display a "thanks for registering" message.

Answer (score 1):

you can use regular expression  of email id check after validation save id in database and and on button behind code of registration write code for sending email using system.net.mail

many email sending function available on internet.

after registeration using coding to check on logon either the email exists in ur database or not.

Answer (score 1):

This is almost a year too late, but for the records you should use the built-in ASP.NET Membership functionality because you get all this (and much more) for free, no need to make e-mail validation logic if it's already made for you is it?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx